# Disable F5 mac shortcut for Dictation

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

I have a company laptop that uses a keyboard different layout than the language I'm using it with - I'm not 100% certain this is the cause but it could be a relevant information.

I'm trying to use some shortcuts in softwares, like VSCode, but anytime I press F5, it doesn't use the F5 I set it up with in the software, but asks if I want to enable VoiceOver, and then dictation after I disabled VoiceOver.

Is there any way to entirely disable F5 as a shortcut for the mac system, to only use F5 as a shortcut in the softwares that mapped it as such?

I'm currently working on a macbook pro M1 with a québec layout, configured as an azerty.

[image: VoiceOver Off]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in the image below that the keyboard shortcut for Dictation is pressing the microphone icon, which is the icon shown on the <kbd>F5</kbd>. You can change this to something else from the proposed menu.

[image: Screenshot of the Dictation section of the Keyboard Settings]

<sup>(Click to open full size)</sup>

Also, if you want to use the function keys, you'll have to hold the <kbd>Fn</kbd> (or Globe) key while pressing the function key you want to use.